# How can I place `GameObject` in my mapbox Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, mapbox, gameobject

I have a map centered at `37.7648, -122.463`. I want to add a `GameObject` to that coordinate or other coordinates. How can I do that in Mapbox Unity? I am creating a Pokemon Go-like game.

[image: Mapbox]

Comment: Have you gone through the tutorials (https://www.mapbox.com/help/unity-mesh-pt-1/) or looked at the POI example that comes with the Mapbox SDK? Look into the MergedModifierStack from tutorial 3 and look at what the code in each modifier is doing.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `GeoToWorldPosition` method.

Example:

```
Vector2d position = new Vector2d(lat, lon);

GameObject go = FindObjectOfType<>.gameObject;
var instance = Instantiate(go, parentAnchor)
instance.transform.localPosition = abstractMap.GeoToWorldPosition(position, true);
instance.transform.localScale = new Vector3(.2f, .2f, .2f);
```